# How to either dump/write a MINI PCI-e wireless EEPROM, or extract/edit an INSYDE bios image

Tags: bios, firmware, eeprom

I want to edit the most recent bios update for my laptop and add the new card's device id's to the wireless whitelist. The bios is insyde, and previously downloading a bios update simply gave you the FD file which you could edit in EZH2O. However, the new bioses are giving a .bin file that I'm unsure of how to extract the fd file from. Any thoughts from the hivemind?

Failing that, I could try dumping the eeprom of the HP card, and then write an appropriate code to the new card to allow it to bypass the bios check. I know there will be further issues as far as drivers go.. but I just need help with this part. So far, I've been unable to get the linux ethtool to work for me. Any other ideas?

much thanks

Comment: Access to the EEPROM will differ for every chipset. You'll need to say which card you're using. If you're hardware-handy it's relatively easy to tap the pins of the EEPROM and dump it out that way, but for that level of effort it's probably easier to just buy a new wireless card.

Comment: @Ian Howson - Thanks for the response.. the point is though that HP laptops are trying to KEEP you from using anything but HP wireless cards. Its totalitarian. That's the reason for the EEPROM change (so that I can make it look like an HP device id for the bios's whitelist). So getting another card won't work (and yes, non hp cards work just fine... its a money move. I can plug the card in AFTER post and it works just fine). As for which card.. specifically an Atheros 9280. I've seen others do it using the ETHTOOL on a knoppix cd.

Comment: I've merged your two unregistered accounts, please consider registering this one or associating an OpenID with it (enabling you to edit your question and leave comments in the future)

Comment: thanks. this is the first time I've been to these sites. People linked me to the others, I didn't know they existed and were connected

Answer (score 1):

I'm not going to be a lot of help generally, but if your system uses one of the newer Ibex Peak or similar chipsets, the Flash is probably operating in descriptor mode.  A quick check for whether this is the case is to look at the size of the .bin file.  If it is 4 MB or 8 MB, that's pretty big for a BIOS, but about right for the BIOS and the

That means you need a program to extract and reinsert the BIOS image (the FD file?).  I have a completely un-guaranteed set of two utilities to do stuff like that for generic descriptor BIOS images.

http://www.wordmark.org/uefi/Extract.exe
http://www.wordmark.org/uefi/InsertBios.exe

Extract.exe sucks out the binary images that go into the descriptor mode SPI image and InsertBios.exe puts a replacement BIOS image into a SPI image. A third utility in the same directory, DumpDesc.exe, prints out some information about the SPI image.  Unfortunately, I don't have any more utilities to help out.  But this might be enough.